# OrientDB - HTTP API: SQL Fetch Plan

Tags: orientdb

From a given Vertex (e.g Employee below), I want to know how to expand edges with their attributes and the vertex at the other end of the edge?  My example below with the response shows the (out_ConfirmedFor=#89:0) edge which has a 'Job' instance as the vertex on the other end).  Id like to construct the SQL request to 'expand' those edges (so I get the nested JSON, not just #89:0).

How can I construct the example request below to do so?  I am not quite sure on how to construct the fetchPlan.  Also, can the fetch plan be part of the request body payload or in the URL only?  Thanks

POST ....:2480/command/mydb/sql/

```
{
  "command": "select from Employee where userName = :userName",
  "parameters": {
    "userName": "paulw"
  }
}
```

and the response is:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "@type": "d",
      "@rid": "#31:5",
      "@version": 26,
      "@class": "Employee",
      "out_ConfirmedFor": [
        "#89:0"
      ],
      "userName": "paulw",
      "@fieldTypes": "out_ConfirmedFor=g"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to obtain information about the connect 'Job' vertex you could query for,eg the property 'name' of the Job, directly
eg.

```
select *,out('ConfirmedFor').name from Employee where userName = 'paulw'
```